# Не появляется кнопка "Ответить" на комментарий WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Не появляется кнопка "Ответить на комментарий" в WordPress. Пробовала различные варианты, сейчас код выглядит так, в functions.php. Подскажите в чем ошибка и что еще я упускаю, пожалуйста?

```php
function enqueue_comment_reply() {
    if( is_singular() )
        wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_comment_reply' );
```

И там где вывод в файле single.php

```php
<?php
    $comments = get_comments();
    $args = array('class' => 'media-object');
    foreach ($comments as $comment) { ?>
        <div class="bs-example" data-example-id="default-media">
            <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left">
                    <?php echo get_avatar( $comment->author_email, 64, '', '', $args); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="media-heading blog-text-uppercase"><?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?></h5>
                    <p><?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?></p>
                    <ul class="list-inline comment-list">
                        <li><?php echo $comment->comment_date; ?></li>
                        <li>|</li>
                        <li><script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js"></script>
                        <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: comment_reply_link используете только внутри цикла комментариев. Смотрите примеры использование в дефолтных темах.

Comment: @Алексей подправила код в описании, вот так полностью выглядит, при этом все равно не выводит кнопку

Comment: get_comments получает простой массив комментариев, в нем нельзя использовать comment_reply_link. Смотрите функцию `wp_list_comments` или шаблон comments.php в дефолтных темах.

Comment: @Katharine Kulikova плагины для статей/комментов используете?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin нет

Comment: Поставьте плагин AnyComment бесплатный от нашего соотечественника и наслаждайтесь его работой, а не исправлением ошибок.